# Class attribute variables - are references or a new object stored?

Tags: java, pass-by-reference

Say I have a code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Animal r1 = new Animal(10,"Amanda");
    House c = new House(100, r1);
    r1.setAge(3);
    
    House c2 = new House(101, r1);
    System.out.println(c);
    System.out.println(c2);
}
```

The output is

```
3 Amanda

3 Amanda
```

So it looks like what java does is store a reference to r1 in the Animal field value in House so that any changes to the object itself are reflected in any call to the Animal variable in the House class. Is that it? Or does java create a whole new object?

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption is correct. Java stores a reference to the animal pointed to by `r1`.

Note that this is **not** the same as pass-by-reference. Java is always pass-by-value, but the values themselves are references.

That means that if you call the constructor of `House` and within the constructor, you assign a new object to the passed in variable, then this won't be reflected to the outside.

```
public House(int id, Animal animal) {
    animal = new Animal(11, "Bertha");
}
```

```
Animal r1 = new Animal(10,"Amanda");
House c = new House(100, r1);
System.out.println(r1);
```

So the abovementioned `println` still prints "Amanda" (and not "Bertha"). The variable `r1` passed into the constructor is not the same as the `animal` variable used within the constructor. The *value of the reference* of `r1` is **copied** into `animal`. Reassigning `animal` has no effect on `r1`.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these House objects share a reference to the same Animal object, just as you suspected.

Note that this behavior is only for objects, not for primitives (int, boolean, float, double, char, ...)